# database schema to relate a table with multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

There is a `purchase_orders` table, which holds purchase orders.

There is another table `emp_payouts` table, which holds payment to be paid to an employee and their details.

There is a `payment_transactions` table which holds payment transactions made to someone from the app, only outgoing payments.

*Each entity (purchase order, employee payouts etc) can have multiple payment transactions.*

***How can I store transactions for both entities in that table?***

I have two solutions in my mind but still I am in doubt.

- Having `purchase_order_id` and `emp_payout_id` in `payment_transactions` table.

  *In this case, one of the column will always hold null values*

  ```
  payment_transactions
  --------------------------
  id    |    purchase_order_id   | emp_payout_id  | amount
  ```
- Having pivot tables for both entities: `purchase_order_transactions` and `emp_payout_transactions`

  *In this case, entities purchase orders and employee payouts are being associated with multiple transactions which is fine, but the same thing is also true for payment transactions. While, a payment transaction should only be related to one purchase order or employee payouts.*

  ```
  purchase_order_transactions
  --------------------------
  id    |    purchase_order_id   | payment_transaction_id  


  emp_payout_transactions
  --------------------------
  id    |    emp_payout_id   | payment_transaction_id
  ```

Comment: How about a single table of `payment_transactions` with columns like `id |  payment_transaction_id  | transactions_type | amount `? Is that workable for you?

Comment: @FaNo_FN  So it will have a column `transaction_type`, but how they will be related to each entity? there will be `payment_transaction_id` in each table i.e. `purchase_orders` and `emp_payouts`? Or what?

Comment: I'm sorry but without the full table structure of `purchase_orders` and `emp_payouts` with a few sample data I'm afraid I'll misunderstand and suggest wrong things. Can you provide more details and maybe with a sample query that you want to work with? thanks

Comment: @FaNo_FN Any simple join query that will get transactions for particular entity. Two entity will be never joined together. It will be to fetch only transaction of particular entity at a time. `SELECT * FROM  purchase_order t1 JOIN  payment_transaction t2 ON t1.id =t2.purchase_order_id` something like this.

Comment: @FaNo_FN Your solution will work, but only I have this problem. *Each entity will have multiple transactions. How will I relate these transaction to concerned entity?*
I can't put `purchase_order_id` `emp_payout_id` and `transaction_type` in `payment_transactions` again, one will be always `null`. I can't either put `payment_transaction_id` in each entity as they will hold multiple transactions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database)

Comment: No it doesn't. How come it be a inheritance model? All the fields are same in both type of transactions. Only the `entity_id` is different. If purchase order transactions and employee payout transaction be two separate table which extends payment transactions, what values will they hold than their ids?

Comment: Ok, let's try this with a fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=590c1943990c66f54972d4567e88a882

Comment: @FaNo_FN That will work, thanks. Just a though, won't it be good to make `id` of the `payment_transaction` to be primary key of each entity rather than storing `transaction_id` .

Comment: Are you referring to `id` in the `payment_transactions`? Actually, I was thinking that `id` is  a primary key while `payment_transaction_id` correspond to the `id` from both `purchase_order_id` and `emp_payout_id` tables.

Comment: Yes, but can it be good if `id` in the `payment_transactions` is the foreign key `purchase_order_id` and `emp_payout_id` ?